# Replaced and increased amount of RAM caused disk transfer rate score to drop

Tags: memory

I just installed 2 new g.skill 4GB sticks of ram to my open slots. The occupied slots contain 2GB a piece for a total of 4GB before the install. My system is now at 12GB but some reason **my disk transfer rate score dropped from 6.3 to a 5.9.** I suppose that seems like a small drop but I was expecting an increase. Compatibility was checked and all seems to work fine.

Last thought, I know you are supposed to rotate every other slot for installation, however I noticed that you are generally guided by your motherboard/ram slots color. My slots are different than some I've seen and are 2 blue 2 black, side by side and not every other so I did NOT remove previous 2GB stick to put a 4 GB between them. The computer boots and runs normally so I'm assuming that isn't the issue, but not sure!

Sorry to be wordy...any help appreciated!

Comment: The system score reported by Windows is basically totally arbitrary. Is there an actual problem here (such as actually slow disk I/O), or are you simply wondering why the number changed?

Comment: So, before the slots were `[2][ ][2][ ]` and now they're `[2][4][2][4]`?

Comment: Before I added any new RAM the slots were [2](blue)[2](blue)[0](black)[0](black). Now they are [2][2][8][8]. 
The motherboard rated its highest at 1333Mhz ddr3 of which both RAM sets are. Only difference is actual memory.
Yes Michael, I was just wondering why the score changed and if I am not realizing some negative affect that may have happened.

Answer (score 1):

There are two main reason this could have happened:

- Speed-matching
- Multi-channel

## Speed-matching

Computers are usually able to work with certain hardware that is not rated for the same speed as expected. They do this by slowing the faster component down to match that of the slower component.

If you put a compatible memory module that is rated faster than the motherboard can handle, it will still work, but it will run at the speed that the motherboard can do, not the speed that the module can do. Likewise, if you put a compatible memory module that is rated slower than the motherboard can handle, the motherboard will reduce its memory-controller speed to that of the RAM module instead of running at its normal speed.<sup>*</sup>

<sub>*This is a general description with *compatible* hardware of differing speeds; it is not meant to be a universal statement.</sub>

Because of this speed-matching ability, if you mix RAM modules of different speeds (which are compatible with the motherboard), all of them will run at the speed of the slowest one.

You did not specify the speeds of the old and new modules, so it is possible that the new ones are slower than the old ones, so the overall memory speed is lower.

## Multi-channel

Computers can use a [multi-channel memory architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-channel_memory_architecture) whereby RAM modules can be matched in pairs (or triplets) so that the system can access two or more groups of modules at the same time in [parallel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_communication) instead of individually in [series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_communication).

The catch is that the modules that are paired must be identical in size and speed. They must also be installed in the correct RAM slots. Exactly how multi-channel can be achieved varies by motherboard.

You indicated that you had two 2GB modules installed, and you added two 4GB modules. It is possible that the system had previously been running in dual-channel mode, but now it is running in single-channel mode. Check your manual to determine which modules to install in which slots to get dual-channel back.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you read the manual for your motherboard.

This is mainly because that way, you can..

1. Understand what frequencies of RAM your motherboard supports
2. Get a recommended setup for how you should distribute your RAM among the slots

Regarding point 2, I don't think it's as relevant considering you've filled all your slots, but checking that your frequencies are equal among sticks would--if I recall correctly--be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should not pay to much attention to this score. It is totally wrong but not precise as a real benchmark. If you really want to check your power, you should try [MaxxPI](http://www.maxxpi.net/index.php) (Maybe build one pair in and out so you can be sure).
2. As Thor already said: check out which frequency your RAM has and what you motherboard supports. And update your motherboard drivers. Once I had a update for my graphics card and my rating dropped from 7.9 to 4.7 and after the next update it came back again (and updates are (nearly) always good). And you should stick the same amount of RAM in the same colored slot. Normally they are split and not pairwise. And also read the manual.
3. Although you shouldn't mix RAM, your PC won't explode, but if you use different RAM sticks (with different frequencies), they will not work as well, as perfectly as complementary RAMs. For example if you have 1333 MHz and 1600 MHz RAM, both will run at 1333 MHz. But don't worry, normally more RAM means better performance, so your RAM is not a bad investment.